# Emulator without GPU emulation detected?

Tags: android, android-logcat

I just want to ask what does this mean "Emulator without GPU emulation detected",how do i fixed this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#acceleration "If you want to have graphics acceleration enabled by default for this AVD, in the Hardware section, click New, select GPU emulation and set the value to Yes."

Comment: @KenWolf What if I am using a virtual device ?

Answer (score 2):

click on checbox

> Use Host GPU

in AVD... That's it....

[image: AVD]